# Talend ESB Runtime SERVER

Tags: runtime, talend, esb, apache-karaf

I have several questions regarding Talend ESB. I'm a Talend DI developer, and web services are new to me. We plan to use the free version of Talend ESB to develop web services. Here are my questions:

In a production environment, what are the best practices? We have developed web services for Customer A and others for Customer B. Should we place all the web services in the same container, or should we separate them into containers for A and B? If separation is recommended, how can we efficiently manage the two containers? Also, how do we deploy a new container?

Is it normal for all services on the same container to use the same port (e.g., 8040/services/)? I noticed that Talend Runtime uses JAAS for security. Is this secure? For the web console, only users with admin roles can access it. However, for SAM (http://localhost:8040/services/sam), it seems that all users, regardless of their roles, can access it. How can we modify the access roles, or is this normal?

Do you have any suggestions for integrating Keycloak into Talend ESB?

What are the advantages of using the subscription version of Talend ESB in terms of security and other features?

I'm trying to use Talend ESB for developing REST web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a production environment, what are the best practices? We have developed web services for Customer A and others for Customer B. Should we place all the web services in the same container, or should we separate them into containers for A and B? If separation is recommended, how can we efficiently manage the two containers? Also, how do we deploy a new container?

Answer : Ideally if there are multiple Services that customers across multiple regions, it makes sense to group these services on different servers by region.
Each server can have a multiple Runtimes under it, i.e.

- Default Runtime(services)
- Route Runtime
  Yes you can spin off multiple Runtimes under a single server.
- You would find all installables on Container-Apps in enterprise version.
- Please see this link for more information : https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/esb-container-administration-guide/deploying-multiple-containers-using-configuration-adaption-scripts

It is also best practice to keep all wrapper services that are called by external application in a single runtime while the internal service that gets invoked by external service should be kept in a separate runtime.